# how to use JSF Converter when the property is not uniquely identifiable

Tags: jsf, converters, uniqueidentifier

In my JSF page, I have a `<rich:autocomplete/>` which must be filled by selecting an object from the list. The `id` of the object does not have useful meaning, so I have to write a `Converter` to change it to readable string.

Unfortunately the string representation of the object could not uniquely identify different objects and so the conversion is not reversible. Now I want to know how I could solve this problem? Is it possible to store the `id` of the selected object into a `<h:inputHidden>` and pass it to the view scoped backing bean?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the input component and the converter the wrong way. You are apparently using the object's string representation (the item label) as input value, while you should be using the object's unique identifier (the item value) as input value. The converter is merely to convert between the custom object and the unique identifier, not between the custom object and the string representation.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i don't understand,as i said i am using <rich:autocomplete/> (version 4) component which does not support for itemValue and itemLabel like <h:selectOneMenu/>. on the other hand i have to show the non-unique property to the user, so how could i achieve this goal?!

Answer (score 0):

I have searched this and until the moment there are no direct solution provided by the rich:component as it does not has itemValue like rich:select

Also there are 2 workaround solution.

1. to use JavaScript to add the id value of the selected item to a
   hidden field    and then use this hidden field to identify the
   selected item
2. I used the fetchValue attribute to concat item_id - item_name
   then I created a converter which substring the item_id to identify
   the selected item.